# When making raspicam, it fails to find OpenCV (which is locally installed) [RaspberryPi]

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

When building making **raspicam**, I need *libraspicam_cv.so* to be produced. For this, I installed **OpenCV** (locally).

During `make`, OpenCV is searched for, but is not being found.

I added `FindOpenCV.cmake` to */usr/local/lib/cmake/*, but am uncertain how to complete this.

OpenCV is located in either */home/pi/installation/* or */home/pi/opencv/*

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: How did you install opencv? Are you trying to write in C++ or Python?

Comment: I'm writing in C++. I installed it following this guide: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/ . In step 5 cmake is set up for installation within an installation folder defined at the start of the guide. Cheers!